# stl map<char*,char*> destructor

Tags: c++, stl

I know that a map destructor calls each of the contained element's destructors. What happens for a

```
map<char*,char*> ?
```

I cannot see where this code is in /usr/include/c++/4.4

---

EDIT:
I should have said

```
map<const char*, const char*, ltstr>
```

like in

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html

Comment: On GCC 4.6 you have to look inside `/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h`
and on 4.6 look inside `/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_map.h`

Comment: Note that a `map` indexed by `char*` probably won't do what you want. It will match on the string address, not the string content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What happens

Nothing. If you dynamically allocated memory, it'll leak - there's no automatic destructor for `char*`.

Use `std::string` or similar class instead.

Comment: Well, "nothing" is probably a bit misleading. All the memory the map allocated internally for its tree gets deleted, after all.

Comment: I think _technically_ it has a destructor that doesn't do anything.  (You can call `A->~char*()`)  But the effect is the same.

Answer (score 14):

When a `map<char*,char*>` is destroyed, so are all of the elements it contains.  Each element's destructor is called, if it is of class type.

However, keep in mind exactly what is contained in your map above.  It isn't strings, as you might expect -- it's just pointers to strings.  The strings themselves aren't destroyed.  Only the pointers are.  `delete` is never called on the pointers.

Case in point:

```
map<char*, char*> strings;

char* key = new char[10];
char* value = new char[256];
/* ... */
strings.insert(key,value);
```

In the above, since `delete` is never called on the pointers created by the calls to `new`, this memory will leak when `strings` goes out of scope.

This is a good illustration of why you should avoid using raw pointers, `new` and `delete`.  In your case, `map<string,string>` would probably be a better choice.

EDIT:

As @sbi mentioned in the comments, another reason why you would want `map<string,string>` over `map<char*,char*>` is because with `map<string,string>` keys are compared by-value, rather than by-pointer-value.

Consider:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    static const char MyKey[] = "foo";
    const char bar[] = "bar";
    typedef map<const char*,const char*> Strings;
    Strings strings;
    strings.insert(make_pair(MyKey,bar));

    string ss = "foo";
    Strings::const_iterator it = strings.find(ss.c_str());
    if( it == strings.end() )
        cout << "Not Found!";
    else
        cout << "Found";

}
```

Fundamentally, you're inserting an element with the key "foo" and then searching for that element.  Test the above code, and you'll find that it isn't found.  If, however, you try this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef map<string,string> Strings;
    Strings strings;
    strings.insert(make_pair("foo","bar"));

    string ss = "foo";
    Strings::iterator it = strings.find(ss);
    if( it == strings.end() )
        cout << "Not Found~!";
    else
        cout << "Found";
}
```

...you get the behavior you **really** wanted.

Comment: Excellent answer, `+1` from me. Another reason to prefer `std::string` is that in a `std::map<char*,T>`, the key will be compared by _address_, rather than by _content_. You rarely ever want that.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree that `std::map<string, string>` will have advantages over `std::map<char*, char*>`. Specially having the key as value rather than pointer would provide the expected search/find results.

But, sometimes we do need pointer in map definition specially in the value part when map’s value part is heavy object of a user defined class. By heavy object , I mean  copy constructor of the class does a significant amount of work. In such scenarios, value part of the map should be a pointer. Using a raw pointer would leak the memory as mentioned above. Smart pointer would be a better choice ensuring no memory is leaked.

Sample example:
Consider the below class

```
class ABCD
{
public:
    ABCD(const int ab) : a(ab)
    {cout << "Constructing ABC object with value : " << a << endl;}

    ~ABCD()
    {cout << "Destructing ABC object with value : "<< a << endl;}

    void Print()
    { cout << "Value is : "  << a << endl;}

private:
    int a;
};
```

Consider the code where-in smart pointer of the above class is used:

```
{
    std::map<_tstring, std::shared_ptr<ABCD>> myMap;
    _tstring key(_T("Key1"));
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(key, std::make_shared<ABCD>(10)));
    auto itr = myMap.find(key);
    itr->second->Print();

    myMap[key] = std::make_shared<ABCD>(20);
    itr = myMap.find(key);
    itr->second->Print();
} // myMap object is destroyed, which also calls the destructor of ABCD class
```

Output from above code is:

```
Constructing ABC object with value : 10

Value is : 10

Constructing ABC object with value : 20

Destructing ABC object with value : 10

Value is : 20

Destructing ABC object with value : 20
```